# Почему в идее некоторые классы выделены курсивом?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Почему в идее некоторые классы выделены курсивом? В интернете не могу найти ответ на этот казалось бы простой вопрос[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-295051/Unclear-logic-of-using-Italic-in-editor-tab-name

Comment: Курсивом выделены классы (файлы, модули) на которые вы тыкнули в дереве проекта, но ничего не правите (просто смотрите). Если тыкнуть на другой файл, вкладка с курсивным названием закроется. Чтобы файл открылся не "курсивом", по нему в дереве нужно щелкнуть двойным щелчком мыши. Или начать редактировать этот файл.

Comment: Большое спасибо!